# Existing DB - SQLite / android - read from db

Tags: android, sqlite

i tried so many times to use an existing data base sqlite in my android app !
i can create a new db, but here , i wanna use an existing one !
this is my codes , there's no problems there , not error ,
but it doesnot work , any one can help me whith it ?

**DataBaseHelper.java:**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.global.getrain/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "BookDB";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }


     public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
            }else{

                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }


       public boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){


            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }


       private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

       public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

        }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "title TEXT, "
                + "author TEXT )";

        // create books table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older books table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");

        // create fresh books table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    // Books table name
    private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";

    // Books Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR };

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        Log.d("addBook", book.toString());
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title
        values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
                null, // nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column
                            // values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    public Book getBook(int id) {

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BOOKS, // a. table
                COLUMNS, // b. column names
                " id = ?", // c. selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                null, // e. group by
                null, // f. having
                null, // g. order by
                null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build book object
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

        Log.d("getBook(" + id + ")", book.toString());

        // 5. return book
        return book;
    }

    // Get All Books
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Book book = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                book = new Book();
                book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

                // Add book to books
                books.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("getAllBooks()", books.toString());

        // return books
        return books;
    }

    // Updating single book
    public int updateBook(Book book) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("title", book.getTitle()); // get title
        values.put("author", book.getAuthor()); // get author

        // 3. updating row
        int i = db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
                values, // column/value
                KEY_ID + " = ?", // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); // selection
                                                                // args

        // 4. close
        db.close();

        return i;

    }

    // Deleting single book
    public void deleteBook(Book book) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_BOOKS, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) });

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteBook", book.toString());

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView obj;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);


        try {

            db.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            db.openDataBase();

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {

            throw sqle;

        }

        /*
         * db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook",
         * "Wei Meng Lee")); db.addBook(new Book(
         * "Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide",
         * "Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy")); db.addBook(new Book(
         * "Learn Android App Development", "Wallace Jackson"));
         * 
         * 
         * // get all books List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
         * 
         * // delete one book db.deleteBook(list.get(0));
         * 
         * // get all books db.getAllBooks();
         */

        obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        List<Book> array_list = db.getAllBooks();

        ArrayAdapter<Book> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Book>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        db.close();

    }
```

PS : i can publish the Book class if that's help !

Comment: There are two ways to do this. Either manually or with the help or SQLiteAssetHelper. It looks like you're trying it manually?. Where is your prepopulated database. It should be in main/assets/database.db

Comment: can you help me with how to do it using : SQLiteAssetHelper (a link can help) , my  prepopulated database is in the folder : assets in : workspace/myapp/assets

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Definitely use this over trying it manually.

Comment: i'll take a look , thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in the assets folder , it must be like that :

assets/databases/

i added the databases folder then it work :D